# Animating particular cells in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, core-animation, uiviewanimation

Is there any way to animate particular cells at launch of a view controller?

[image]

Above is a collectionView cells, and at launch of the screen it needs to show the 2nd item is selected and at the same time needs to show left and right cell with slight fade in animation. What is the best way to achieve this animation? I'm already using custom flowLayout animation for the custom carousel animation. My main question is how to make 1st and 3rd cell animated on viewDidLoad?

Comment: If you have any idea of using 3rd party libraries my recommendation would be "https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel". It has multiple animation styles.

Comment: @Bharath I'm already using my own custom layout flow to do sliding carousel animation. My question is how to make 1st and 3rd cell animated on viewDidLoad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to make same type of animation by playing with **UICollectionViewFlowLayout**.

You can view the final result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eN24P.jpg

Basically I used [UPCarouselFlowLayout Library](https://github.com/ink-spot/UPCarouselFlowLayout) to achieve this animation.

I added **sideItemOffsetShift** to the custom flowLayout:

```
//  UPCarouselFlowLayout.swift
//  UPCarouselFlowLayoutDemo
//
//  Created by Paul Ulric on 23/06/2016.
//  Copyright © 2016 Paul Ulric. All rights reserved.

public enum UPCarouselFlowLayoutSpacingMode {
  case fixed(spacing: CGFloat)
  case overlap(visibleOffset: CGFloat)
}

class CustomLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
  fileprivate struct LayoutState {
    var size: CGSize
    var direction: UICollectionViewScrollDirection
    func isEqual(_ otherState: LayoutState) -> Bool {
      return self.size.equalTo(otherState.size) && self.direction == otherState.direction
    }
  }

  @IBInspectable open var sideItemScale: CGFloat = 0.6
  @IBInspectable open var sideItemAlpha: CGFloat = 0.0
  @IBInspectable open var sideItemShift: CGFloat = 0.0
  @IBInspectable open var sideItemOffsetShift: CGFloat = 50.0
  open var spacingMode = UPCarouselFlowLayoutSpacingMode.fixed(spacing: 10)

  fileprivate var state = LayoutState(size: CGSize.zero, direction: .horizontal)


  override open func prepare() {
    super.prepare()

    self.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    let currentState = LayoutState(size: self.collectionView!.bounds.size, direction: self.scrollDirection)

    if !self.state.isEqual(currentState) {
      self.setupCollectionView()
      self.updateLayout()
      self.state = currentState
    }
  }

  fileprivate func setupCollectionView() {
    guard let collectionView = self.collectionView else { return }
    if collectionView.decelerationRate != UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast {
      collectionView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast
    }
  }

  fileprivate func updateLayout() {
    guard let collectionView = self.collectionView else { return }

    let collectionSize = collectionView.bounds.size
    let isHorizontal = (self.scrollDirection == .horizontal)

    let yInset = (collectionSize.height - self.itemSize.height) / 2
    let xInset = (collectionSize.width - self.itemSize.width) / 2
    self.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(yInset, xInset, yInset, xInset)

    let side = isHorizontal ? self.itemSize.width : self.itemSize.height
    let scaledItemOffset =  (side - side*self.sideItemScale) / 2
    switch self.spacingMode {
    case .fixed(let spacing):
      self.minimumLineSpacing = spacing - scaledItemOffset
    case .overlap(let visibleOffset):
      let fullSizeSideItemOverlap = visibleOffset + scaledItemOffset
      let inset = isHorizontal ? xInset : yInset
      self.minimumLineSpacing = inset - fullSizeSideItemOverlap
    }
  }

  override open func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
    return true
  }

  override open func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
    guard let superAttributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect),
      let attributes = NSArray(array: superAttributes, copyItems: true) as? [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]
      else { return nil }
    return attributes.map({ self.transformLayoutAttributes($0) })
  }

  fileprivate func transformLayoutAttributes(_ attributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes {
    guard let collectionView = self.collectionView else { return attributes }
    let isHorizontal = (self.scrollDirection == .horizontal)

    let collectionCenter = isHorizontal ? collectionView.frame.size.width/2 : collectionView.frame.size.height/2
    let offset = isHorizontal ? collectionView.contentOffset.x : collectionView.contentOffset.y
    let normalizedCenter = (isHorizontal ? attributes.center.x : attributes.center.y) - offset

    let maxDistance = (isHorizontal ? self.itemSize.width : self.itemSize.height) + self.minimumLineSpacing
    let distance = min(abs(collectionCenter - normalizedCenter), maxDistance)
    let ratio = (maxDistance - distance)/maxDistance

    let alpha = ratio * (1 - self.sideItemAlpha) + self.sideItemAlpha
    let scale = ratio * (1 - self.sideItemScale) + self.sideItemScale
    let shift = (1 - ratio) * self.sideItemShift
    let offsetShift = (1 - ratio) * self.sideItemOffsetShift
    attributes.alpha = alpha
    attributes.transform3D = CATransform3DScale(CATransform3DIdentity, scale, scale, 1)
    attributes.zIndex = Int(alpha * 10)

    if isHorizontal {
      attributes.center.y = attributes.center.y + shift

      if normalizedCenter < collectionCenter {
        attributes.center.x = attributes.center.x - offsetShift
      } else {
        attributes.center.x = attributes.center.x + offsetShift
      }
    } else {
      attributes.center.x = attributes.center.x + shift
    }

    return attributes
  }

  override open func targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset proposedContentOffset: CGPoint, withScrollingVelocity velocity: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
    guard let collectionView = collectionView , !collectionView.isPagingEnabled,
      let layoutAttributes = self.layoutAttributesForElements(in: collectionView.bounds)
      else { return super.targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset: proposedContentOffset) }

    let isHorizontal = (self.scrollDirection == .horizontal)

    let midSide = (isHorizontal ? collectionView.bounds.size.width : collectionView.bounds.size.height) / 2
    let proposedContentOffsetCenterOrigin = (isHorizontal ? proposedContentOffset.x : proposedContentOffset.y) + midSide

    var targetContentOffset: CGPoint
    if isHorizontal {
      let closest = layoutAttributes.sorted { abs($0.center.x - proposedContentOffsetCenterOrigin) < abs($1.center.x - proposedContentOffsetCenterOrigin) }.first ?? UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes()
      targetContentOffset = CGPoint(x: floor(closest.center.x - midSide), y: proposedContentOffset.y)
    }
    else {
      let closest = layoutAttributes.sorted { abs($0.center.y - proposedContentOffsetCenterOrigin) < abs($1.center.y - proposedContentOffsetCenterOrigin) }.first ?? UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes()
      targetContentOffset = CGPoint(x: proposedContentOffset.x, y: floor(closest.center.y - midSide))
    }

    return targetContentOffset
  }
}
```

And in my viewController I have:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // scroll to index 1 
    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: 1, section: 0)
    collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: false)

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.updateCollectionView()
    }
  }

  func updateCollectionView() {
    if let layout = collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as? CustomLayout {

      UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        layout.sideItemAlpha = 0.6
        layout.sideItemOffsetShift = 0
        self.collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
      })
    }
  }
```

So by default when the collection is loaded, side items are hidden. Then we call **updateCollectionView()** to update the **sideItemOffsetShift** and **sideItemAlpha**.

Comment: Where are those `@IBInspectable`s displayed in IB? Can't find them :-/ Is this even possible for custom layouts?